# Creating a workbook with a custom name using Excel.createWorkbook(base64)

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js

I am trying to create a copy of Excel Workbook from the base64 stream as explained in below Excel API documentation in my Office JS web Add-In

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview#function-details

A new workbook is created successfully with a excel auto generated name "Book1" or "Book2" if Book1 already exists then it creates with Book2 and goes on.

But I a requirement to create the new Workbooks with a given name from our backend. As we have downloadable reports we want to name them as for e.g. "Q2 Expense Report". Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Thanks, Office Platform team